# Заключить в скобки часть строки с условием

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть фрагмент программы с GCODE. (Это пример)

```
G1X-10.599Z12
X9.4Y800
Y70.190
X18.3
X25Z13
```

Чтобы сделать макрос требуется заключить значение X в квадратные скобки.Должно получиться так:

```
G1X[-10.599+#1]Z12
X[9.4+#1]Y800
Y70.190
X[18.3+#1]
X[25+#1]Z13
```

как можно это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Начало я могу заменить так:

```
/X/g ==> /X[/
```

Конец не удаётся сделать.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/EqyigT/1

Comment: Немного не соответствует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
re.sub(r'X([^A-Z]+)', r'X[\1+#1]', text)
```

См. [пример регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/SGVQyU/1).

- `X` - символ `X`
- `([^A-Z]+)` - Подмаска №1: один и более символов, отличных от заглавных латинских букв.

[Код](https://ideone.com/jyBZCl):

```
import re
texts = ["G1X-10.599Z12", "X9.4Y800", "Y70.190", "X18.3", "X25Z13"]
for s in texts:
  print( re.sub(r"X([^A-Z]+)", r"X[\1+#1]", s) )
```

Результат:

```
G1X[-10.599+#1]Z12
X[9.4+#1]Y800
Y70.190
X[18.3+#1]
X[25+#1]Z13
```